# Access a 2nd level node in XML using Linq to XML

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml, xmlnode

I have the following XML file :

```
<tree>
    <branchs>
         <branch id=1>
             <apple id=1 color=green/>
             <apple id=2 color=red/>
         </branch>
         <branch id=2>
             <apple id=1 color=green/>
             <apple id=2 color=red/>
         </branch>
    </branchs>
</tree>
```

I would like the SQL command to access to the apple id#1 from the branch id 1, and than to change the color (on the first time) and then to be able to remove this apple from this branch.

I tried the following to remove an apple, but without any result

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(myxmlFile);
var result = (from selectedApples in 
                (from selectedBranch in doc.Element("Branchs").Elements("Branch) 
                where selectedBranch.Attribute("id").Value == 1 
                select selectedBranch)
                where selectedApples.Attribute("id").Value == 1
                select selectedApples).ToList();

 result.ToList().ForEach(apple => apple.Remove());
```

I suppose I made a mistake... I suppose too I'm not so far from the solution...

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Well not sure it is the optimized solution... But it is working.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(myxmlFile);
var results = from selectedApples in doc.Root.Element("branchs").Descendants()
                where selectedApples.Attribute("id").Value == 1
                select selectedApples.Elements("apple");

foreach(var result in results)
    result.Where(a => a.Attribute("id").Value == 1).ToList().Foreach(a => a.Remove());

doce.Save(myxmlFile);
```